# Hibernate Criteria API condition "like" with integer

Tags: string, hibernate, integer, sql-like, criteria

In my database I have a column "year" which is an integer.

How can I search by using Criteria API (not by HQL) which records contain, for example "196..." in the year column?

I think it should be `Restrictions.like`, but I got exception:

> SEVERE: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a better and faster solution would be to use Criterion.sqlRestriction(String sql). You can form the sql as, "to_char(year) like '19%'", be aware that to_char is database specific. I dont think JPA supports to_char function.

Comment: And when using this don't forget to escape the chars (to prevent SQL Injection)!

Comment: another issue is i have join of tables and both table have "year" column, in this scenario again it throws error.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the exception should tell you everything you need. The `Restrictions.like` in your case is looking for an Integer, but got a String as a parameter. (you should have posted the exact call of the `Restrictions.like` used).

Nevertheless there is a `Restrictions.between` method. You could use that for your problem. For example:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("year", 1960, 1970));
```

There are also alternative methods. Integers can be compared with `Restrictions.le` (less or equal), `Restrictions.lt` (less than), `Restrictions.gt` (greater than), `Restrictions.ge` (greater or equal).