# Using like to non-string columns in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm currenty working on a `Grails` query service that involves retrieving row/s from the database with a specific criteria called `filterText`.

```
List getAdjustmentCodes(params) {
    def filterText = params.filterText
    .
    .
    .
    adjustmentCodeList = AdjustmentCode.findAll{
        or {
            ilike('description', "%$filterText%")
            // ilike('id', "%$filterText%")
        }                       
    }

    return adjustmentCodeList
}
```

Notice that I've comment out the line `ilike('id', "%$filterText%")` because when the program reaches that line, it throws an error:

> `org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type java.lang.Long for value...`

This is *probably* because the `id` column of that table is of type `long`:

```
class AdjustmentCode implements Serializable {
    Long id
    String description
    String type
    String status
    Date statusDate
    String lastUpdateBy
    Date lastUpdateDate

    static mapping = {
        table 'RFADJUSTCDOTB'
        version false
        id column : 'ADJUS_CD'
        description column : 'ADJUS_DESC'
        type column : 'ADJUS_TYPE'
        status column : 'ADJUS_STATCD'
        statusDate column : 'ADJUS_STATDTE'
        lastUpdateBy column : 'ADJUS_LUPDBY'
        lastUpdateDate column : 'ADJUS_LUPDDTE'
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

But I need to use the `like` operator for this column. For instance, the user wants to search for an adjustment with a `code` similar to: `00002312123`. Is this the right way to use the `like` operator, or are there any other way. Thank you for answering.

I've seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22912640/4043409), but it doesn't tell how to use non-strings on a `like` in an `or` clause.

Comment: What if you use plain `like`? e.g. `like('id', "%$filterText%")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate Criteria API condition "like" with integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841531/hibernate-criteria-api-condition-like-with-integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here is an alternative:

```
class AdjustmentCode implements Serializable {
    Long id
    String description
    .....
    String idAsString
    static mapping = {
        table 'RFADJUSTCDOTB'
        ...
        idAsString formula('to_char(id)') // Or use an equivalent fn to convert it to a String
}
```

You could then use ilike as follows:

```
ilike('idAsString', "%${filterText}%")
```

It's a lazy way out I suppose, but it should work.

Comment: Or... the easiest way is to change the `Long id` to `String id`.

Answer (score 1):

`ilike` only work on `Strings` (text). You can't use it on other data types. It doesn't make sense to use insensitive (which is related to Strings). This isn't a limitation of Grails or Hibernate, but rather the way SQL functions.

Use the `like` operator instead.

This question has been asked before, and [has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841531/hibernate-criteria-api-condition-like-with-integer) (from a hibernate perspective).

Comment: Just tried `select * from table_a a where a.id like '%1'` and it worked.

Comment: What database engine are you using? SQL spec shouldn't allow for that.